# Spring: using of FlatFileItemReader

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Could I use FlatFileItemReader not as reader of batch processing? I want to use it for parsing of File.

I have bean of reader:

```
<bean id="cvsFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="resource" value="file:${garmin.fs.in.received2}" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="names" value="id,sales,qty,staffName,date" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="my.app.util.ReportFieldSetMapper" />
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And I want to use it in my component:

```
@Component
public class Handler {

    @Autowired
    private FlatFileItemReader<Report> reader;

    public File handleFile() {
        try {
            Report report = reader.read();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return input;
    }          
}
```

But in line of code:

```
Report report = reader.read();
```

I got exception:

org.springframework.batch.item.ReaderNotOpenException: Reader must
    be open before it can be read.

Is it possible to use spring batch reader in the following way?

Answer (score 0):

As the exception implies, you have to call `reader.open()` before calling `read()` for the first time.

You should also call `reader.close()` when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

As @GaryRussell wrote you can call `open/close` but - IMHO - use a SB component outside of SB domain is not a good approach because you couple your classes with SB classes too tight.

For me a better and more clear mode to operate is to use a CSV parsing library as [BeanIO](http://beanio.org/) as main component and reuse it in your `Handler` as well as with [BeanIOFlatFileItemReader](http://beanio.org/2.0/docs/api/org/beanio/spring/BeanIOFlatFileItemReader.html) as reader.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement ItemStream and override open, close and update method as below-

```
@Component
public class Handler implements ItemStream {

    @Autowired
    private FlatFileItemReader<Report> reader;

    public File handleFile() {
        try {
            Report report = reader.read();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return input;
    }  

    @Override
    public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) {
        reader.open(executionContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) {
        reader.update(executionContext);

    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        reader.close();

    }        
}
```